# Font Awesome Icons only printing in Black

Tags: html, css, printing, fonts, font-awesome

I am developing a website that must print a page that contains Font Awesome icons. The issue is that when you go to print, the Font Awesome icons will not print in color.

In the browser they show up in color, but when the page is printed the icons are solid black. Is there anyway to make the Font Awesome icons print in color? Perhaps through CSS with @media print { }?

EDIT: Also, I am developing in firefox.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turns out that the item that you actually need colored isn't the `i` itself but its `:before` element. Thus:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .fa:before { color:red; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 11):

If you are using bootstrap you need to edit its CSS since it's specifies black color for "@media print"

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am using bootstrap. I should have said that in my question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Surely there's a way to do it without modifying bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

I just put together a simple HTML example using font-awesome and it seems to work fine in Chrome and Firefox for me. I see the icon in red onscreen and it also prints in red without any further action. Having said that, creating a separate media CSS is a good idea if your HTML page warrants it, since it can provide a better user experience (onscreen view isn't always ideal for printing).

Are you sure you don't have a printer setting modified to not print in color? Is the printer out of that color and thus defaults back to just plain black? Have you tried it in another browser (Chrome, Safari, Opera, IE)?

Here is the simple code I used for testing:

```html
<html>
 <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <title>Fontawesome Test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   .fa { color:red; }
  </style> 
 </head>

 <body>
  <i class="fa fa-camera-retro">  Testing color</i>  fa-camera-retro 
 </body>
</html>
```